# Plone LDAP/AD authentication encryption

Tags: active-directory, ldap, plone

We have a Plone 4.3 site on debian 7 that we'd like to authenticate against an existing AD controller. Using the excellent plone.app.ldap product we have this working, but the 'manager' username/password are being sent over the wire in plain text.

No doubt this is because we are using the protocol: 'LDAP' and not 'LDAP over SSL', our problem is how to implement 'LDAP over SSL' on the AD server in a way that works with Plone. Has anyone had any experience configuring the AD machine to accept these types of requests?

From what I understand it needs to be a new service on a new port, similar to https (i.e. not TLS), but I don't know enough about AD to know what to ask the AD admin mob.

---

EDIT: following the comment from **@Martijn Pieters** I add that if we set the 'manager dn usage' to not always then we get this error in the event log:

```
OPERATIONS_ERROR: {'info': '000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1', 'desc': 'Operations error'}
```

Thanks for any ideas.

-i

Comment: Doesn't your LDAP AD server contain *hashed* passwords instead?

Comment: hi, the passwords sent back about the users are hashed yes, but the password used to connect in order to get them ("manager DN") is sent in clear, as viewed via wireshark.

Comment: Right, for that you'd need to use an SSL connection indeed. Does [this blogpost](http://rpatterson.net/blog/ldap-certificates-and-buildout-oh-my) help at all?

Comment: well yes it does indeed. thanks very much i hadn't found that one. now i need to learn how ldap certificates work. do you want to submit an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up the LDAP connection to use a certificate instead of a password.

Ross Patterson [outlines the procedure](http://rpatterson.net/blog/ldap-certificates-and-buildout-oh-my), but the mailinglist post he links to is gone. The same thread is however [still available on GMane](http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Plone-ldap-over-TLS-td4633613.html).